# Using SDL with Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, sdl, xcode4.3

I've decided to learn c++ and try to make a game with SDL framework. The problem is that I don't know how to use SDL together with Xcode 4.3, since I can't use it like a template, as seen in other guides. Would be great if someone could help me get SDL to work with Xcode 4.3.

EDIT:
I try add SDL to Xcode project following http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/using-sdl-with-xcode-4/

When I try to compile I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article should help you:

[Using SDL with Xcode 4](http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/using-sdl-with-xcode-4/)

Comment: I do exactly as said in the article. After I add header search path and try to compile I get the following errors: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Take a look at how you define the main() function in your code. SDL is very picky on how you define main(). You can see an example on how to define main() in the comments to the article I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It took a quite long time until I got SDL and Xcode running. So, don't care. :-)

I uploaded [here](http://www.michaeldorner.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/SDL_Template.zip) a simple SDL template for Xcode 4.5 and Mac OS X 10.7 and 10.8 (also using OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile possible). Step by Step instructions:

1. Download [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15.dmg) (at the moment version 1.2.15)
2. Open the downloaded .dmg file
3. copy the `SDL.framework` into `/Library/Frameworks/`
4. Done. You can use the Xcode template (you should see a red area):
   [image]

Further details and an image on my [Blog](http://www.michaeldorner.de/?p=2644) (only german, sorry).